# How to Set my URL pattern in my php using get method parameters only

Tags: php, url, get

I have 3 php files in my directory(/account):

1. index.php
2. login.php
3. signup.php

Accessing the folder in my localhost:

http:localhost/account ==> opens the default(index.php file)

I want to access the login.php and signup.php using:

```
   => http:localhost/account?login
```

and

```
   => http:localhost/account?signup
```

respectively.

Here is my code in the index.php

```
<?php 
if($_GET['login']){
        include('login.php')
} else {
        // Load homepage of the site
        // which in my case http://localhost
}
if($_GET['signup']){
        include('signup.php')
} else {
        // Load homepage of the site
        // which in my case http://localhost
}
```

Please help to get me a way to get my URLs like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the key login and signup but no value so you should check whether the key exists with `isset()`.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['login'])){
        include('login.php')
} else {
        // Load homepage of the site
        // which in my case http://localhost
}
if(isset($_GET['signup'])){
        include('signup.php')
} else {
        // Load homepage of the site
        // which in my case http://localhost
}
```

In case you want to use `switch` instead,

```
switch(true) {
    case isset($_GET['login']):
        ... break;
    case isset($_GET['signup']):
        ... break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you use switch in getting this done incase i have plenty of php files?